# PyCharm can't see class from pyTables

Tags: python, pycharm, pytables

I've actually asked this question for PyDev and got a working answer: [PyDev can't see class from PyTables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16668152/pydev-cant-see-class-from-pytables)

Basically, pytables must be added to builtins, and there is an option in pydev for this. However, I could not find a way of applying the solution in PyCharm. How can I add a forced builtin to PyCharm? Refreshing caches, reinstalling everyting etc. does not work. Some types from pytables are not visible to the ide, and I can't work with code that contains false positives for errors.

ps:I've asked the question in PyCharm forum with no response. I will update that question if I can get an answer in SO. [see it here](http://forum.jetbrains.com/thread/PyCharm-1506)

Here are the details of my settings with screenshots, plus the error screenshot:

[image: settings]
[image: error]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Code completion works for the classes from your sample in the PyDev question when using pytables 2.2.1 version from sourceforge.

Note that PyCharm [finds the `tables` package](http://img90.imageshack.us/img90/2074/20130524120432.png) if it's installed for your project interpreter using the Windows installer.

No errors are displayed in the editor:

[image: no errors]

I was able to reproduce the problem with 2.4 `pytables` version (installed from [this site](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) together with `numexpr` and `numpy-MKL` dependencies).

It appears to be an issue with parsing the package files. I've [reported a bug](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-9873) to PyCharm issue tracker, please vote.

Comment: My PyCharm finds the tables package as well. PyTables  is installed using the windows installer package, and passes all tests. Is that different from "installing for my project interpreter"?

Comment: No. Please clarify the problem then. What classes are not resolved? Does it help if you delete [system directory](http://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/entries/23358108) and restart PyCharm?

Comment: At the moment StringCol and any other descendants of Col are not resolved. I've deleted the system dir, and started PyCharm, which asked for all the stuff it does when it is installed for the first time. I've typed in the exact same sample snippet which you also used, and StringCol is not visible. If I run the code, it runs correctly.

Comment: Provide the screenshots of your project interpreter (active), packages installed for this interpreter and the error you have displayed in the editor. Check idea.log for possible errors. If I F4 on the StringCol, PyCharm navigates me to [this file](http://img441.imageshack.us/img441/2934/20130524131103.png). Do you have the same file on your system?

Comment: I have the same file. The screenshots are now in the question. There is only one interpreter in this machine and that is naturally the project interpreter.

Comment: You are using 2.4 version, I tested with 2.2.1 from sourceforge pytables site. Please try the older version.

Comment: I will do that, but it does not actually help me use the version I want to use, plus the original question remains: is there a way to tell pyCharm to add tables to builtins? pydev simply has a way to do this. I really appreciate all your help, but unless there is a way to convince pycharm, I can't use 2.4, which is what I'd like to use :)

Comment: Updated the answer, bug reported for PyCharm.

Comment: Thanks, since this appears to be a bug, I guess your effort to track it down is worth the mark for correct answer :)